# Comparing values from sheet1 with sheet2 values

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
For i = 1 to 9999
    If sheets ("sheet1").cells (i, 5).value >= sheets ("sheet2").cells (i, 8).value And sheets ("sheet1").cells (i, 5).value <= sheets ("sheet2").cells (i, 11).value then

    Sheets ("sheet1").cells (i, 10).value = "true"
```

What the code is suppose to do is check if value on sheet1 is within a range of values between two figures on sheet2. But it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Other than the misplaced spaces (`Sheets ("Sheet1")` should be `Sheets("Sheet1")`) and the fact that it's commented out... it looks fine to me. What does "Doesn't seem to work" mean? It says (for clarification) if the contents of column E is between column H and K then print "true" in column J. Is that what you want it to do?

Comment: ...I assume when you're actually running the code, the lines aren't commented out?

Comment: Well, try uncommenting the code...

Comment: Yes @ JNevill. @ brucewayne no comments when actually running the code.

Comment: I'm not sure we can offer more help here without more information.  Is it erroring, is "True" not showing up. Can you share some sample data and your desired results?

Comment: True shows up on empty rows only

Comment: Post some sample data from your sheet, give us a few rows from Sheet2 columns A:K and the same number of rows from Sheet 1 columns A:E

Comment: Also step through your code using F8 and evaluate each of the tests in the debug window so you can see where exactly your results are not what you expect.

Comment: Also don't do this: `For i = 1 to 9999` do this instead: `For i = 1 to Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row` No need to keep testing rows where you have no data.

Comment: how do i send the sample data? via email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub workbook_initialize()

Dim cell As Excel.Range

Dim LastRow As Long



LastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
For i = 1 To Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


If cell.Value >= Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 8).Value And cell.Value <= Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 11).Value Then


Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell.Row, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value




End If
Next i
Next


End Sub
```

I was able to achieve what i wanted with this code. which is to loop through a particular range of cells in sheet1 and if any cell has value greater  than or equal to value in sheet2 column H and at the same time less than or equal to the value of sheet2 column K on same row then make sheet1 column J same value as the corresponding cell in sheet2 column C.

Comment: despite that the code worked i discovered a new problem when i tried to add  an else statement to rather write a string on any cell in sheet1 column J that doesnt meet the condition. i'lld be much grateful if i could get a solution to this new problem.